# Time Complexity bound for this 3 nested loops

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

i need help finding the theta bound to this nested for loops

```
for(i=1;i<n;i++)
  for(j=1;j<i;j*=2)
    for(k=1;K<i;K*=2)
       count++
```

my intuitions is that the answer is nlog^2(n) but i can't prove it.

thank you in advance.

Comment: In the inner loop `i` is reset to 1 so how will the loops stop?

Comment: it was a writing mistake it supposed to be k

Comment: @AdamShapira, k seems to do nothing now?

Comment: Well if it helps: my feeling says that your answer is correct, but I also couldn't prove it.